# Spring MVC view is not detected

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tiles, apache-tiles

Few days ago this configuration works but now I have get:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name '' in servlet with name 'XXX'
```

for:

```
http://localhost:8081/resourceArea/save
```

My controller looks like:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/resourceArea")
public class ResourceAreaController{
....
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String save(@ModelAttribute @Valid ResourceArea aEntity, BindingResult aBindingResult, Model aModel, SessionStatus status,
                   HttpSession session) {
...
}
```

My views are configured with tiles they works perfect before:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_0.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>
<definition name="base.definition"
            template="/WEB-INF/pages/layouts/layout.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Pit 2 Web Demo"/>
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/pages/layouts/header.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="menu" value="/WEB-INF/pages/layouts/menu.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="content" value=""/>
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/pages/layouts/footer.jsp"/>
</definition>

<definition name="home" extends="base.definition">
    <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/pages/home.jsp"/>
</definition>

<definition name="denied" extends="base.definition">
    <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/pages/denied.jsp"/>
</definition>

<definition name="/*/*" extends="base.definition">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="{2} {1}"/>
    <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/pages/{1}/{2}.jsp"/>
</definition>

<definition name="/raw/*/*" template="/WEB-INF/pages/layouts/empty.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/pages/{1}/{2}.jsp"/>
</definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

It is strange because this happen only for save action.

Comment: In Spring The String returned in a method must match to a view filename! What are you returning in your save method? Does ist actually need to return sth? Can't you just use void?

Comment: Seems that save view is not called at all :| so problem is in invoking view

Answer (score 0):

change your method from

```
public String save(...)
```

to

```
public void save(...)
```

or as an alternative (and since your `save` method is a `POST` action) you may want to implement the [PostRedirectGet paradigm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)

```
public String save(...){
    // do whatever you want here
    return "redirect:another view";
}
```

Comment: Is fixed, it calls on return other method, rather than other view. Something like : return index();